# Location changed notification android

Tags: android, gps, location

I am just testing out the onLocationChanged method in Android , I have implemented a way that when I click a button the app returns a String with the new lat and lng values. But now I am trying to show the results automatically every time the location changes. This is what I have so far to do so:

```
location manager

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   

int minTime = 30000;
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
MyLocationListener myLocListener = new MyLocationListener();
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, minTime, 1, myLocListener );
```

onlocationchanged

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

  if(loc != null){

  lat1 = loc.getLatitude();
  lng1 = loc.getLongitude();
  
  currentlocation = "Location changed to lat: " + lat + "" + "lng: " + lng1 ;

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = currentlocation;
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
   
  
  }
```

}

I have set the requestlocationupdates method to request and update every 60000 millseconds
My problem is that the application never toasts the lat and lng values when the location changes. I have tested the app with the emulator and tried telneting the lat and lng values. And I have also drove around in my car to see if the values change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
currentlocation = "Location changed to lat: " + String.valueOf(lat1) + "" + "lng: " + String.valueOf(lng1) ;
```

and for test you can just use:

```
requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER...
```

Comment: Thanks goodm it worked perfectly, Do I have to use .GPS_PROVIDER or could I use the best provider the device can find ? cheers again

Comment: You can use your one, I use GPS_Provider, to check it is really working. If it help, could you "up" my answer :)